# Bootstrap - pause Carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

What I want to do is to pause my carousel when hovering with the mouse over ANOTHER div.
I tried to use jQuery and .hover for this:

```
$('#running-box, #bg-car').carousel({})

    $("#running-box").hover(function(){
        $("bg-car").carousel({interval: false});
    });
```

But it isn't working.
The reason I took interval:false is another post from here, also this won't work:

```
$('#running-box, #bg-car').carousel({})

    $("#running-box").hover(function(){
        $("bg-car").carousel('pause');
    });
```

I mastered every bootstrap stuff, fading transitions, affixing my menu but this simply won't work. Live Demo: http://mentsik.eu/kerek/

This is just a test site for testing Bootstrap.
My Javascript is like in the examples, in an own applications.js

Comment: Just an fyi, but your example has `$('bg-car')` when you probably mean `$('.bg-car')` or `$('#bg-car')`.  That could be 1 reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `#running-box` is the element you want to use as the hover target AND `#bg-car` is the one with the carousel, the following will work:

```
 $("#running-box").hover(
    function(){
        $("#bg-car").carousel('pause');
     },
    function() {
      $("#bg-car").carousel('cycle');
    }
  );
```

Please note your example has `bg-car` without a period or #.